# reverse() on spawns in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am reading doc of cocos2dx on Actions (link: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Actions). They mention reverse function on sequences and spawns at the bottom.

I am just a little confused what difference would reverse make on spawns, since according to what I understand spawns in cocos2d corporate actions together and make them happen at the same time? If this is true reverse would make almost no variations to spawns, at least visually? There is one (potential) line of explanation in the doc says "However it is not just
simply running in reverse. It is actually manipulating the properties of the original Sequence or Spawn in reverse too." Is it because of this "properties" that there is really some difference, probably somewhere in bottom level? Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Spawn::reverse()` is special. One thing I like Cocos2d-x is that I can see the source code by clicking F12.

```
Spawn* Spawn::reverse() const
{
    return Spawn::createWithTwoActions(_one->reverse(), _two->reverse());
}


//Definition of Spawn
Spawn{
//...
protected:
    //FiniteTimeAction is a derived class of Action
    FiniteTimeAction *_one;
    FiniteTimeAction *_two;

private:
    CC_DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(Spawn);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the reverse will not make any visible visually as it will be reversing every action and there will be no movement.As I am giving an example of jumpBy and reversing the jumps of the sprite using a sequence.

```
auto jump = JumpBy::create(3,Vec2(100, 0),50,3);
auto jumpBack = jump->reverse();
sceneSprite->runAction(Sequence::create(jump,jumpBack, nullptr));
```